# How do you add a company logo to google web app?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have developed two web applications for my organisation a searchable staff directory and contact form.  Both work as expected and I'm happy with them, however I have been unable to add our brand image.  This is stored locally on my C: drive and I cannot seem to point to a local route directory in google app script as I would in a text editor such as Atom or Brackets.  I have added the code index.html file below assuming that's all you need, if you require the code.gs I can add this too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
    /* Base Styles -------------------- */

      h2 {
        padding-top: 20px;
      }

      /* Main Styles --------------------- */

      .main-header {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        background: linear-gradient(180deg, #141760, #007DAD, transparent 90%);
        background-size: cover;
        border-radius: 25px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="primary-content container form-group">
      <header class="main-header d-block bg-primary text-white text-center">
        <p class="title">Promoting </p>
        <h1>AUE</h1>
      </header>
      <div id="container" class="primary-content form-group">
        <h2>Contact us</h2><br>
        <form id="responderForm">
           <input type="text" name="firstName" class="input-field form-control" placeholder="First Name:" required><br>
           <input type="text" name="lastName" class="input-field form-control" placeholder="Last Name:" required><br>
           <input type="email" name="email" class="input-field form-control" placeholder="Email:" required><br>
          <select id="service" class="input-field form-control">
            <optgroup class="input-field form-control" label="Request information about our services">
              <option value="Volunteering" name="service">Volunteering</option>
              <option value="Home Help Service" name="service">Home Help Service</option>
              <option value="Befriending Service" name="service">Befriending Service</option>
              <option value="Information & Advice" name="service">Information &amp; Advice</option>
              <option value="Advocacy" name="service">Advocacy</option>
              <option value="Fundraising" name="service">Fundraising</option>
              <option value="Marketing" name="service">Marketing</option>
              <option value="Chief Executive Office" name="service">Chief Executive Office</option>
              <option value="Invoice Query" name="service">Invoice Query</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup class="input-field form-control" label="Get in touch with Human Resources">
              <option value="Reference requests" name="references">Reference Requests</option>
              <option value="Employment Opportunities" name="references">Employment Opportunities</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup class="input-field form-control" label="Contact us about GDPR">
              <option value="Consent" name="gdprRights">Withdraw Consent</option>
              <option value="Right Of Erasure" name="gdprRights">Right to Erasure</option>
              <option value="Data Subject Access Request" name="gdprRights">Data Subject Access Request</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select><br><br>
          <label id="enquiry_label" class="text-label">Please enter your message below:</label><br>
            <textarea id="enquiry_form" class="text-input form-control" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="event input-field btn btn-outline btn-primary"><br>
        </form>
      </div>
      <footer class="main-footer text-center">
        <p>Helping people.</p>
        <p>&copy; All rights reserved to </p>
      </footer>
      <script>
        const myForm = document.querySelector('#responderForm');
        console.log(myForm);
        myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let myData = {
        'first' : this.querySelector('input[name="firstName"]').value,
        'last' : this.querySelector('input[name="lastName"]').value,
        'email' : this.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value,
        'service' : this.querySelector('select[id="service"]').value,
        'enquiry': this.querySelector('textarea[id="enquiry_form"]').value
        }

        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).addData(myData);
        console.dir(myData);
        })

        function onSuccess(data){
          console.log(data);
        }
     </script>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I assume I can add an image stored in a local directory, but would appreciate guidance on how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATED code below:

```
<body>
    <div class="primary-content container form-group">
      <header class="main-header d-block bg-primary text-white text-center">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/open?id=1caqBFth6-DyKwrHTG3-F-lGak" style="height: 200px; width: 200px;">
        <p class="title">Helping people</p>
        <h1>AUE</h1>
      </header>
```

Comment: Why not just upload to drive?

Comment: @TheMaster ah yes, of course.  I just need to point to the file in drive using the DriveApp?

Comment: file should be public. point to it's download url. Alternatively,  datauris: base64 string should work

Comment: @TheMaster thank you.  I have added the url but I'm doing something wrong as no image is appearing, would you mind pointing me in the right direction? I've added the code above.

Comment: Like I said, you should use the download url

Comment: @TheMaster thank you for putting me on the right track :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload the file to Google Drive and serve it from there. There are 2 things however that you need to do inorder for you image to be displayed correctly.

1. Set the image to 'anyone with the link can view'
2. Add the download URL to the `img src=""`

To create a direct download URL you need to append the file ID to the following link;

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=
```

So you should have something like;

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1caqBFth6-DyKwrHTG3-F-lGak"
```